# CORS error when making network call in useEffect in Next.Js

Tags: reactjs, cors, next.js

Was making a network call in `getStaticProps` to APIs of `superhero.com` which worked but when I tried making the same in `useEffect` it is throwing CORS error.

> Access to fetch at 'https://superheroapi.com/api//1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have tried making network calls using *fetch* as well as *axios* but getting the same error. Does the problem or limitation lie with Next.js?

Edit: Tried using *JSON placeholder* APIs in `useEffect` and it is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: It is a very reasonable error and has nothing to do with Next.js, the thought that it would occur didn't cross my mind and posted here in the spur of the moment. @engineforce in the answers explains it very succinctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CORS

CORS errors happen when you're trying to access resources from one domain on another domain. It only happens in the browser, and is a security feature.

So essentially, when you're fetching data from `https://superheroapi.com/api/1` while on `localhost:3000`, the browser first asks `superheroapi.com`, "hey, can this domain fetch data from you?". `superheroapi.com` will then say, "I only accept requests from these domains". If `localhost:3000` is not in that list, you'll get a CORS error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

You can change the domains that `superheroapi.com` accepts via the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You can do it manually, or there's a handy npm package that will take care of that for you in Next.js.

### Fix CORS in Next.js

By default in Next.js, the CORS header is restricted to same-domain traffic only. However, you can change this.

Next.js actually has a guide in their docs on adding a CORS header to api routes.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#connectexpress-middleware-support

In short, though, first install the CORS package.

```
npm i cors
# or
yarn add cors
# or
pnpm add cors
```

Then add it to the API route.

```
import Cors from 'cors'

// Initializing the cors middleware
const cors = Cors({
  methods: ['GET', 'HEAD'],
})

// Helper method to wait for a middleware to execute before continuing
// And to throw an error when an error happens in a middleware
function runMiddleware(req, res, fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (result) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result)
      }

      return resolve(result)
    })
  })
}

async function handler(req, res) {
  // Run the middleware
  await runMiddleware(req, res, cors)

  // Rest of the API logic
  res.json({ message: 'Hello Everyone!' })
}

export default handler
```

*Code snippets are taken from the Next.js docs. All credit goes to the makers of Next.js for them.*

Comment: I tried this and when I make a POST request from the same Next App it passes through. Shouldn't it throw an error as POST request is not allowed in methods?

Answer (score 3):

Code in `useEffect` runs in the frontend/browser therefore must obey the CORS. `getStaticProps` runs at build time, therefore do not have the CORS limitation.

If superheroapi.com API is under your control, you should add CORS response headers to fix the issue. Otherwise you need to create a reverse proxy, e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

Comment: Please see the edit. And what is the solution to resolve the CORS error?

Answer (score 1):

You must run your code on a domain that is validated.
Some api give you cors error for localhost request.

Simple way is: Try to define a local domain (Change your local dns for that domain to 127.0.0.1 in host file) and write a server.js file like this.
Replace 'next.yourdomain.com' with your domain ;)

```js
const { createServer, } = require('http');
const { parse, } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

// const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const dev = false;
const app = next({dev, });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const HOST = 'next.yourdomain.com';
const PORT = 8090;

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  }).listen(PORT, HOST, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Starting Next.js at http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

Then run

`next build && node server.js`

Also you must discard this file on your final deploy.